# How can I gain exposure to long term treasuries across the entire globe?

Tags: etf, bonds, vanguard

A "Long-Term Treasury" fund typically holds US government debt with a long expiration date, for example, 20 to 30 years in the future. It is frequently cited as a useful portfolio component for example in a "60 / 40 Portfolio" (where the 40% is treasuries).

Two funds that offer this US-specific portfolio are VGLT and TLT. However, it seems difficult to easily buy long-term government debt from non-US countries.

How can I gain exposure to long-term government bonds from many countries around the world?

Comment: FYI there was a bit of discussion about this kind of question here: https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2874/366 - ideally answers would address the general problem and not just recommend specific products.